# Como itero elementos de 2 Arrays para agregarlo en uno solo? (JS)

Tags: javascript, array

Estoy nuevo en Javascript y en StackOvf tengo este problema:

Debo crear una función que reciba dos arreglos como
parámetros y devuelva uno nuevo con los elementos de ambos, de 1 en 1.
Ejemplo:

- mezclarArreglos([1,2,3,4],[“h”,”o”,”l”,”a”]) debe retornar [1, “h”, 2,”o”, 3,”l”,4,”a”]
- mezclarArreglos([“h”,”p”], [1,2,3,4]) debe retornar [“h”, 1, “p”, 2, 3 , 4]

---

No se como iterar en ambos y agregarlos sin que la longitud de cada uno lo limite...
desde ya GRACIAS <3
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```js
function mezclarArreglos(arr1, arr2){
  const res = [];
  const lower = arr1.length <= arr2.length ? arr1 : arr2;
  const higher = lower == arr1 ? arr2 : arr1;
  
  for(let i = 0; i < higher.length; i++){
    if(lower[i]) res.push(lower[i]); res.push(higher[i]);
  }

  return res;
}

console.log(mezclarArreglos([1,2,3,4],["h","o","l","a"]));
console.log(mezclarArreglos(["h","p"], [1,2,3,4]));
```

Principalmente, tenemos que guardar en memoria cual es arreglo con mas elementos (`higher`) y cual es el que contiene el menor numero de elementos (`lower`), y entonces iterar siempre sobre el que mas elementos posee (`higher`).

```
for(let i = 0; i < higher.length; i++){
    
}
```

En el proceso tendremos que tener otro array para guardar el resultado, en este caso lo declaramos arriba de nuestro codigo:

```
const res = [];
```

Seguidamente dentro de nuestro `for` como el elemento que siempre debe ir de primeras es el del array con menos elementos, debemos de comprobar si ese array posee en la pocision actual un elemento, que en caso de ser asi le agregamos a nuestro resultado esa pocision de memoria en el array:

```
//El arreglo mas pequeño en esa pocision tiene un elemento
if(lower[i]) res.push(lower[i]);
```

En caso de que el arreglo mas pequeño en la pocision `i` no posea un elemento, entonces simplemente no lo añadimos a la lista, luego de esta operacion simplemente procedemos a añadir el elemento `i` del arreglo mas grande:

```
res.push(higher[i]);
```

Aqui no tendremos que preocuparnos por validar nada debido a que como estamos iterando sobre el mas grande, sabemos que ese posee un valor.

Comment: AMIGO! sos un C A P O <3 
me había pasado por la mente esa posibilidad pero no sabia expresarla en código. 20/10